# WMI Permission for monitoring agent

Tags: permissions, wmi

I have an monitoring system that require WMI permission to deploy the monitoring agent, we need it to upgrade, uninstall, install the agent on the VMs, I can see that the WMI is allowed on the AD servers, but denied on file, exchange servers etc..

I have a GPO that manage the permissions for the agent AD user and I created an WMI Filter on the GPO to link to the GPO (this gpo gives admin permissions to the agent user) but it is still not working on the others servers. When I try to uninstall the agent from an exchange server i.e I got this error message

> Failed to replace agent files to match version 8.1.5.500. An error occurred querying service cuAgent on XXXXX
>   Failed to contact 'XXXXXX' using WMI with the following error:
>   Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>   In order to assure correct WMI connectivity, please make sure that the following command can be invoked successfully from this machine:
>   wmic /AUTHORITY:"Kerberos:XXXX\XXXXXX" /NODE:"XXXXXX" /user:XXXXX\XXXXX /password:********** SERVICE list full

Comment: Something seems to have gone wrong at the end of the error message (`permissions.trong text*`?) - please check.

Comment: @greybeard sorry, ignore this part please